# Extract line from multi-line cell that starts with specific character

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a multi-line cell in **A2**:

[image: my current progress]

and my goal is to:

- extract all lines that start with `/`
- remove in-between empty cells.

My formula in cell **B2** is:

```
=(iferror((ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A2,CHAR(10)),"^/.*"))),""))
```

It is extracting all cells that start with `/` but keeping **empty cell between**.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
=filter(split(A2, char(10)&"/"), regexmatch(split(A2, char(10)), "/.+"))
```

For an arrayformula you could try

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A10, "(?:^|\n)([A-Z]+)",), char(10)), "/",))
```

(Change range to suit)

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A, " ", "♦"), CHAR(10))), "^/(.*)")), , 999^99)), " "), "♦", " "))
```

[image: 0]